# Sum of 1 column to be displayed for all rows in a dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a case where I insert multiple datasets into a temp table. At the end, I would like to display the total number of rows for these multiple datasets across all the rows of the temp table. For example:

```
cnt1   name    age
300    peter   21
200    piper   22
```

Desired result set:

```
cnt1   name    age
500    peter   21
500    piper   22
```

This is the outcome I am looking for at the end of a very long stored procedure. I am not able to figure out how to add up on a single column and display the sum across all the rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With window function:

```
select sum(cnt1) over() as cnt1, name, age
from TableName
```

**EDIT:**

```
select (select sum(distinct cnt1) from TableName) as cnt1, name, age
from TableName
```

Comment: How do we make sure that it adds only the distinct cnt1 values? I think we cannot add the DISTINCT with OVER clause. Any workarounds for that? Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: Thanks Giorgi. The edit works like a charm. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (you can use `union all` to append it to your earlier results if you want).

```
Select sum(Cnt1) over () as Cnt1, name, age
from MyTable
```

My answer originally used `over (partition by 1)`, but I see that that is unnecessary.

Comment: @Giorgi 's response is similar but better.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Cross join with a subquery that returns the grand total:

```
select gt cnt1, name, age
from mytable
cross join (select sum(cnt1) gt from mytable) x
```

Comment: @rvphx I would be interested to know how this performs in comparison to the windows function approach of the other answers

Comment: I will surely try this once I have a working piece. I will report back to you what I find. Thanks for taking the time to answer.